# Manipulate model list entirely on client side w/jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Forgive me if this is a bit vague, but I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this task.  Let's say I have a list of users in a model:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class EditDocumentModel
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In the view, there is a type-ahead search box (jQuery code) to find users and then an "add" button.  The view also displays a list of users currently attached to the document and there are buttons to remove them.  Skipping details of this code because it's irrelavent to my question.

Instead of posting back the entire form when users are added and removed from the user list, I'd like to keep the list manipulation entirely on the client side.  I would handle the click of Add and Remove buttons and make adjustments to the list of users being displayed.

When the form is posted back to the server, I'd like to be able to bind to the list the client created in jQuery.

A couple of specific issues that I'm stuck on right now are:

1. If I generate the user list on the server using razor, then I'd have to duplicate that code in jQuery to add/remove users without going back to the server every time.  Duplication is a terrible thing.  I could use a partial for a user list item and ajax, but that defeats the purpose of not making multiple round trips to the server as users are added and removed.  I also thought about just not having any server side code to generate the "visible" list and doing it all in the client code when the page loads, but I'd still have to have server side code that puts the data into the view somehow where the client code could get at it.
2. How to get the binding to work?  Would it be acceptable to try and generate the form values the way MVC expects them to be on the return trip?  I thought about simply stuffing all the user Id's into a string and on the post, populate a form value with the CSV list and Split() it on the server side.  Well that just seems cheezy but it's all I got.

But more in general, I'm looking for a good "recipe" for how to do something like this.  I'm sure this has been done in many different ways.  I'm just having a difficult time finding what they are.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your "visible list" is not persisted to a database or the like, but is simply built by the user as needed, there is no need to duplicate code between the server and client.

I assume you're using an AJAX call to retrieve a list of matching users from the typeahead search box. You can use client side code to allow the user to build and edit a subset of that list. That code should generate elements within a form that will post the appropriate back to the server when the user submits it.

The default MVC model binder can bind lists of objects to method arguments if you pass them as an array. Your form elements names should take the form `argumentName[i].PropertyName` where `argumentName` corresponds to an array argument in the method signature, `i` to the index of the object in the list, and PropertyName corresponds to a property of your object.

If you simply need to pass an array of Ids to the controller method for example, your client-side code might generate an array of hidden elements like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="/Controller/SubmitForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="users[0].UserId" value="12345" />    
    <input type="hidden" name="users[1].UserId" value="12346" />    
    <input type="hidden" name="users[2].UserId" value="12347" />    
    <input type="hidden" name="users[3].UserId" value="12348" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm(User users[])
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could format the names like that and the binding would work.  Thanks for the tip.  And for building the list, I found I could use `MvcHtmlString.Create(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model.Users))`, put that in the ViewBag, and then access it from javascript.  Getting a lot closer!

Comment: Are you returning the whole of your user table to the browser and then filtering it from the typeahead using jQuery? Sounds excessive unless you have a very small user table. In any case, if you're wanting to pass JSON data for processing on the client, I'd say there are better ways to do it than that.

Comment: The list on the model is small.  It does seem a little hackish.  Perhaps I'll find a better way. Thanks Paul.